# Stack Exchange Data Explorer query to find upvoted questions with only downvoted answers

Tags: sql, sql-server, stackexchange

I have written a SQL query against the Stack Exchange Data Explorer that identifies answered questions with a positive score for which all the answers have a negative score (this was an answer to [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247898/224428), though the code in that post is different from what I've posted below).

It's a fairly straightforward query; you can see it and run it [on the Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/revision/269442/357063/) (where you can also examine the schemata of the tables), and I have reproduced it below for your convenience.

```
SELECT
  q.Id AS [Post Link], -- this alias makes the Data Explorer do magic link rendering
  MAX(q.Score) AS [Score],
  COUNT(a.Id) AS [AnswerCount],
  AVG(CAST(a.Score AS float)) AS [AvgAnswerScore]
FROM
  Posts AS q
  -- INNER JOIN => At least one answer
  INNER JOIN Posts AS a
    ON q.Id = a.ParentId
WHERE
  -- Question has a positive score
  q.Score >= 1
GROUP BY
  q.Id
HAVING
  -- Zero answers with a non-negative score
  SUM((CASE WHEN a.Score >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) = 0
ORDER BY
  [Score] DESC,
  [AnswerCount] DESC
```

While I of course would love to hear anything you have to say about this code, I am particularly interested in the following:

- Stylistic tips - coming from the perspective of a PEP8-adhering Python guy, the huge inhomogeneity in SQL coding styles makes me queasy.
- `MAX(q.Score)` looks really stupid and is semantically wrong, since there's obviously only one `q.Score` for each `q.Id` since they come from the same table, and `q.Id` is the primary key of that table. But putting `q.Score` into the GROUP BY also seems weird to me, since that's not semantically what I'm doing either. Is there a better way to approach this?
- How do the performance characteristics of the HAVING clause here differ from instead using a WHERE clause of the form below?

  ```
  q.Score >= 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Posts AS a2
    WHERE a2.ParentId = q.Id AND a2.Score >= 0
  )
  ```

  My sense is that `HAVING SUM(...) = 0` is probably better, since, uh... there doesn't need to be a new subquery for each row of the outer query? But I don't know if that is true or even makes sense.

Comment: This isn't a review of the query so much, but your problem statement should be more clear.  Should this return questions with answers that have no votes at all?  Should this return questions with no answers?  Should this return questions with answers with a positive score but having at least one downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your questions in reverse order…

Your `HAVING` clause is clearer than than an anti-join condition in the `WHERE` clause.  It is also more efficient — tick the "Include execution plan" checkbox to see how much more complicated the anti-join is.  You could do better, though:  `MAX(a.Score) < 0` also means that all answers have a net negative score.

Given the choice between selecting `MAX(q.Score)` and grouping by `q.Score`, I'd prefer the latter.  Both are annoying, but the SQL standard requires that you do one or the other, so that all columns are either mentioned in `GROUP BY` or are aggregated.

I can provide some style tips, but keep in mind that these are my personal recommendations.  I don't believe that there is a standard SQL style guide — and certainly nothing as formalized as PEP 8.

- Fill in the description to your Data Explorer query.  Otherwise, there is a huge gap between the information contained in the title and the SQL.  Detail exactly what the query does.  Mention your motivation for writing the query.  State what the sort order is.
- Indent more.  The `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `ORDER BY` clauses are all subsidiary to the `SELECT`, and therefore should be at the next indentation level.
- Finishing the query with a semicolon is a good habit.
- Move comments to the right to be less obtrusive.
- I like to put commas *before* the selected columns.  That convention makes it easier to add and remove columns.
- Prefer comparing with 0 instead of comparing with any other constant.

```
SELECT q.Id AS [Post Link] -- Alias makes Data Explorer do magic link rendering
     , q.Score AS [Score]
     , COUNT(a.Id) AS [AnswerCount]
     , AVG(CAST(a.Score AS float)) AS [AvgAnswerScore]
    FROM Posts AS q
        INNER JOIN Posts AS a
            ON q.Id = a.ParentId
    WHERE
        q.Score > 0        -- Question has a positive score
    GROUP BY
        q.Id, q.Score
    HAVING
        MAX(a.Score) < 0   -- Best answer has a negative score
    ORDER BY
        [Score] DESC,
        [AnswerCount] DESC;
```

I'd like to point out: good job remembering to `CAST(a.Score AS float)` before taking the average.  SQL Server is tricky, in that `AVG()` of `int`s is an `int`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Re: "prefer comparing with 0" - is there a SQL-specific reason for this, or is it just the usual maxim of "don't use magic numbers in your code"?

Comment: CPU instruction sets have special instructions for comparisons with zero. (In practical terms, you aren't going to notice much of a performance difference, but it's a general aesthetic principle that 0 is a nice number to compare against.)